# @PersistenceContext and static property

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

now its time to ask noob question about JPA.

I've got a simple app, so want to make a simple dao class for all my entities.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class GenericDAO implements Serializable {

public GenericDAO() {
}

@PersistenceContext(unitName="TestAppPU")
public static EntityManager em;

public static <T> void save(T smth) {
    em.persist(smth);
}
public static <T> void merge(T smth) {
    em.merge(smth);
}
public static <T> void remove(T smth) {
    em.remove(smth);
    em.flush();
}

public static <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> cls) {
    return (List<T>) ((Session) em.getDelegate()).createCriteria(cls).list();
}
}
```

I tried to use it like that:

```
testEntitys =GenericDAO.getAll(TestEntity.class);
```

But it crushes with NullPointerException about the "em" in getAll(), so it looks like it is not set with @PersistanceContext as I expected.

@PersistanceContext works fine when I use it in the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean {


    @PersistenceContext(unitName="TestAppPU")
    public EntityManager em;

...    
testEntitys = em.createQuery("select t from TestEntity t").getResultList();
...
```

So it looks like persistance.xml is configured right. But I dont want to pass the em to the GenericDAO.

So my question is how to achieve @PersistanceContext working GenericDAO as I expected (second code sample) and does it really possible or I should inject dao classes in every bean where I want to use persistance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Injecting into `EntityManager` into `GenericDAO` there did not work because `GenericDAO` is not managed. Instead if the class was a session bean or a managed bean, then injection would have worked.

That apart, a few other points to note

- Creating an `EntityManager` is not a costly operation. So when you want to operate on entities you can just inject the `EntityManager` on the required class and directly use the methods on `EntityManager`. (Sidenote: `EM` Injection into servlets is to be avoided )
- This `GenericDAO` doesn't seem to offer much. `EntityManager` is already generic enough and you can just directly use it.
- Lastly, a warning on the use of `static` variables and methods. I'd advise against it for the sake of testability and thread-safety.

Using `@Stateless` beans with `EntityManager` injected as DAOs is one common practice.

To summarize, you can simply inject `EM` in any class that needs to do entity operations without even using DAOs. If you wished for separation of concerns, you can have a `Stateless` bean with `EM` injected as a DAO

Answer (score 0):

Spring can understand @PersistenceContext annotations both at field and method level if a
PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is enabled.

```
<!-- bean post-processor for JPA annotations -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

As an alternative to defining a PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor explicitly,
consider using the Spring context:annotation-config XML element in your application context
configuration.

```
<!-- post-processors for all standard config annotations -->
<context:annotation-config/>
```